# Is there a simple circuit which would behave similarly to a diode, but with a higher cut-in voltage?

Tags: analog, diodes, cut-in

I was wondering if there exist any relatively simple circuit which would have an I-V characteristic similar to that of a diode (i.e. exponential but small before the cut-in voltage) but with a higher cut-in voltage. I know I could just have several diodes in series but this quickly becomes impractical as I need the cut-in of around 5V which means around 8 diodes in series.

EDIT: Actually, what is important for me is that diode to have a smoother knee in the I-V characteristic. The more evidently exponential the thing the better.

Comment: Connect a battery in series with the diode

Comment: A transistor with voltage divider might do it.  Do you really need a specific curve when the diode comes on.  Just basically on/off at some voltage allows for more options.

Comment: Yes, I do need a specific curve as the setup is to be used in the feedback path of an opamp to create a log amplifier. I just want to extend the 'exponential' region of the response of the amplifier.

Comment: LED or Avalanche diode have higher cut-in voltages. But I am not sure about the curve.

Comment: Which part of a standard diode's I-V curve is not exponential enough for you?

Comment: Try the circuit of a "transdiode" (a "reversed" transistor connected in the negative feedback loop of an op-amp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important is the exponential part of the I-V?
As @nidhin suggested, 2 LED's in series could work.
or a 5V zener.. or a 2 2.5V zeners in series.
The low voltage zeners are somewhat exponential,
but not as good as diodes.

> EDIT: Actually, what is important for me is that diode to have a
>   smoother knee in the I-V characteristic. The more evidently
>   exponential the thing the better.

OK then try 2 LED's.

Answer (score 0):

The Maxim application note "Integrated DC Logarithmic Amplifiers" covers principles including temperature compensation and reports over 5 decades dynamic range using a MAX4206 i.c.

See http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3611