# How can I make a log amplifier's logarithmic region span across the range of 0-5V input instead just working close to 0V?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, diodes

I need to implement a log amplifier. Currently I'm doing it using a diode in the negative feedback loop but it only really gives me the log response close to the zero input, with the amps output quickly becoming proportional to the input (around 0.2V). Is there a way to make this logarithmic region span the entire length of the 0-5V input domain?

Comment: Tried increasing the value of resistance at the input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple circuit which would behave similarly to a diode, but with a higher cut-in voltage?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156375/is-there-a-simple-circuit-which-would-behave-similarly-to-a-diode-but-with-a-hi)

Comment: The questions are related but I wouldn't say they are a duplicate. The question you linked asks for a device with more exponential I-V characteristics and this one asks for logarithmic gain. One solution can lead to another but it doesn't have to.

Comment: Show us your circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two resistors to reduce the input range of 5 volts to 0.2 volts.

Comment: True, that will force move the response of the system into the  logarithmic region but also it will reduce the range of the outputs (kinda important because I want to them sample it with and ADC).

Comment: Amplify the output with, maybe, an op-amp.

Comment: Sample it with the ADC first and then apply the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try the circuit of a "transdiode" (a "reversed" transistor connected in the negative feedback loop of an op-amp).

[image]

Comment: This is basically what the OP has done already isn't it? The transistor behaves like a diode in this configuration.

Comment: One issue with this, is that the transistor like all pn junctions are temperature sensitive. If I recall the temperature effects can be quite significant to the output. If more accurate results are needed, then a temperature compensated log converter would be needed.